# to fetch the seq_no of the columns in plsql

Tags: plsql

How to get

table1

```
column1
123 -seq_no
```

table2

```
column1  column2
123     1
123     2
123     3
```

how to get the column2 of table2 for column1 seq no of first table.

Please help

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What does it mean? Do you want to put TABLE1.COLUMN1 into TABLE2.COLUMN1 or vice versa? Or something completely different?

Comment: Why PL/SQL specifically? This looks like a query, not a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Littlefoot,

What you are asking is a very basic question, one that might be expected of someone who has never had any training in PL/SQL. This will get you started, but I strongly suggest you look for some getting started training.

```
 DECLARE
     l_col_result   table2.column2%TYPE;
 BEGIN
     SELECT column2
       INTO l_col_result
       FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column2;
 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (a => l_col_result);
 END;
```